# Codeigniter - php to js and/css

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm developing a web application using codeigniter and I want to dynamically generate a CSS and a JS file.

By that I mean, depending on which modules a user uses on the site, it should include different CSS and JS files. Something like this for the CSS:

```
foreach($modules as $module){
  include('path/to/module/css');
}
```

I'll save this inside a class called 'modules' and inside a function called 'get_css()'.  So the codeigniter link will be: http://somesite.com/modules/get_css

But I want the server to think that this is a css file and I would also like for it to not be inside my application (ie: application/controllers) as this could be a security threat.  But instead be in the root directory.

I'm supposing I have to do something with htaccess, and maybe create another file that gets the content from that page?  I have actually no idea how to do either, and/or if it's the correct way.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: I think it would be a lot easier for you to create *links* to static (but existing) CSS files. If you're dealing with more than a few lines of Javascript, you're probably better off splitting them out and linking to them as well. (Dynamically generated JS can be a pain to debug)

Comment: But users on average will have more than 10 modules on a page, so I would need to include 10 different CSS and 10 different Js scripts on each page just for the modules.  That'll be 20 scripts which will slow down my site, won't it?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Whether they slow down your site depends on how big they are...I've rarely seen a CSS file go over a couple kb, and if you use a Javascript library like jQuery you could probably cut your scripts down a bit...

I did a lot of dynamic JS for years while I was working with classic ASP, and I remember it being a huge headache to debug and maintain. (Though there were times we had no choice)

Comment: Tim, I have to disagree.  Modern tools like WebKit's built in inspector and Firebug for Firefox make it relatively simple to debug dynamic JS/CSS, especially if care is taken to output comments in the dynamic file showing where one source file begins and ends.  denislexic has a legitimate concern in having too many included files.  20 extra requests per pageview can slow down your web stack in a hurry, especially if all the requests are going through a fully featured webserver like Apache or IIS.

Comment: I'll clarify that I do agree with you in that the page should link to existing static files to save some CPU cycles, but those files can (and probably should be) be dynamically generated.

Comment: @Casey - I love FireBug, and I agree it's useful...but my experience - both from inheriting dynamically generated HTML/Javascript written by other developers and (masochistically) doing it myself, has been it can get painful quick.

Answer (score 3):

You could make your get_css() method retrieve the contents of the CSS files, merge them together and then output a *cached* CSS file to disk.  It would be helpful to use a hash to name the files so you only generate merged CSS files for each unique combination of modules.  So you'd merge the contents of all the files and name it as:

```
$output_filename = md5( $module_a_name . $module_b_name ... ) . '.css' ;

if (! file_exists( $output_filename ) {
    //generate merged CSS file
}

// Call back to your template layer to include $output_file in the page header
```

By checking if that file already exists on the server, you can prevent the re-work of generating the files, and then simply output a style include in your template pointing at the resulting file.  No .htaccess changes necessary, just let files just get served in the same way as your other static content.

I'm by no means a security expert, but as long as PHP is configured to write these files no a non-executable directory and you don't use user input to grab the source CSS files you should be fine.  You'll also need to clear the cached CSS files when you update the source CSS files.